# Getting queryString from GET request from website- alternative Tools then Selenium

Tags: json, testing, selenium-webdriver, query-string, key-value

**Aim:**
I´m testing a specific site and I want to check wheater the sent key-value-pairs are valid.

I need to **get the queryString parameters (key-value-pairs) of a GET request on a website**. The queryString is only accessible via the GET requests and is **NOT** in the url. (I want to **compare these key-value-pairs** from the website later with other key-value-pairs from a file/html/..etc.)

**This is what I did and know until now:**

- I know I can visualize the K/V-pairs when using FireBug->Network->Parameters.
- I can get a GET request with the Selenium WebDriver, but it is complicated to extract the queryString out of the JSON-Object. [I was using Java with jsoup and json.simple]
- The only tool I know which can compare key-values on a website is Columbo.io, but I have to write the compared values manually into the tool- that is not flexible enough for my purpose.
- In my research I found the following tools: PhantomJS, Ranorex, SmartBear TestComplete, Wetator, Sahi Pro, RedGlass, TestingBot, BugBuster, Canoo Webtest. **I sadly cannot find out if these tools are able to give me the key-value-pairs I desire.**

**Problem:**
With Selenium I expect to need a lot of time for writing tests, like maybe 2-4 weeks? So I am searching for other tools which can extract the key-value-pairs of a website easier or quicker.

**Question:**
Which tools can you recommend for getting these parameters easily? 
And if there isn´t any better tool then Selenium then please tell me: maybe I´m overlooking some other issue and there are i.e. better API´s for parsing the JSON-Object to get the key-value-pairs or other things I could improve?
Are there any sites where I can read the experiences of other persons with specific tools.

PS: This is my first question here on Stackoverflow. I hope you can understand and help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your point correctly but if you want to play with HTTP requests and key-value-pairs, you may have a try to perform with [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/overview-summary.html) which can be integrated with your Selenium-Webdriver java. Hope it can help.